# How to send money to customer's bank acounts via stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

So I have this application where customers can invest in something and then after sometime they can double their money.

I am using stripe checkout to receive payments from the customer and it is working. But I don't know how to send money to the customers that they have won to their bank accounts.

Do every person need to have a stripe account to transfer money to their banks. I just want to send money to their bank.

Please tell me a solution to this. What should I do. I also want customers who does not have a stripe account else this will limit my website users. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/en-de/connect) for this. This way each of your customers will have a Stripe account that will be connected to your Platform. This way you can pay out funds into different bank accounts.